# javascript find object name in an array

Tags: javascript

```
a=[{'report1':{'name':'Texas'}},{'report2':{'name':'Virginia'}}]
```

From the above javascript object I need to extract only 'report1' object.
I can use foreach to iterate over 'a' but somehow need to extract 'report1' object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way I can think of is using the [`.find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var obj = a.find(o => o['report1']);
```

If there is no matching element in the array the result will be `undefined`. Note that `.find()` is an ES6 method, but there is [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) you can use for old browsers if you need it.

To get to the object that `report1` refers to you can then say `obj['report1']`.

In context:

```js
var a=[{'report1':{'name':'Texas'}},{'report2':{'name':'Virginia'}}];

var reportToFind = 'report1';

var obj = a.find(o => o[reportToFind]);

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj[reportToFind]);       // {'name':'Texas'}
console.log(obj[reportToFind].name);  // 'texas'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `filter`:

```
var report1 = a.filter(function(obj){ return obj['report1'] })[0]
```

`report1` will be an object, or undefined

Introduced in ES5 probably supported by most new browsers.

See: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Array_methods_Array.prototype.filter

Comment: If you're going to use an arrow function, might as well go *short*: `a.filter(obj => obj['report1'])`...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to grab it:

```
var report1 = null;

for ( var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++ )
{
  if ( 'report1' in a[i] )
  {
    report1 = a[i].report1;
    break;
  }
}
```

Demo:

```js
a=[{'report1':{'name':'Texas'}},{'report2':{'name':'Virginia'}}];

var report1 = null;
    
for ( var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++ )
{
  if ( 'report1' in a[i] )
  {
    report1 = a[i].report1;
    break;
  }
}

console.log('report1', report1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`, `String.prototype.replace()`

```js
var a = [{'report1':{'name':'Texas'}},{'report2':{'name':'Virginia'}}];

var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a, ["report1", "name"])
          .replace(/,\{\}/, ""));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It answers the question, in a unique and interesting way.

Comment: What is purpose of "downvote" without description where expected result is returned?

Comment: I didn't vote this down, but note that it doesn't return the object, it returns an array containing the object.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, you are technically correct, though gist of expected result is returned at stacksnippets; i.e.g.; `res` array contains only filtered object, given `js` at OP, and `res[0]` would provide the filtered object at index `0` of `res` array

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[{'report1':{'name':'Texas'}},{'report2':{'name':'Virginia'}}]
for(var report in a){
 var reportRow = a[report];
 if(reportRow['report1']){
 var report1Extract = reportRow;
 }
}
console.log(report1Extract);
```